# For Loop Repeating numbers in each line

Tags: for-loop

I'm confused on how to produce this output with the numbers in each row.
I was able to get the .'s to work but i'm not sure what formula to use to make each line contain the line's amount of numbers.
....1
...22
..333
.4444
55555

Comment: Which language? Here is JS example:    function printNums(numToPrint) {

    for(var i = 1; i <= numToPrint; i++)
    {
    var strToPrint= "";
      for(var k = 0; k < i; k++)
      {
        strToPrint += i.toString();
      }
        console.log(strToPrint);
    }
    }

    printNums(5);

Comment: Please share the code you've tried and the language you are using

Comment: I'm using Python. This is as far as i've gotten i just can't figure out the print statement to produce the line number * itself but consecutively.                 def print_numbers2():
    for i in range (1, 6):
        print("." * (i * -1 + 5), end="")
        print(i

Answer (score 0):

Here's a javascript implementation. If there is no repeat function available for you in Python, you might right one. This is pretty!

```js
for( i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ) {
    let s = '.'.repeat( 5 - i ) + ( i + '' ).repeat(i);
    console.log(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code implementation with for loops:

```
int count = 5;
for (int i = 1; i < count+1; ++i):
    for (int j = 0; j < count-i; ++j):
        print ".";
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j):
        print i;
    print ' ';
```